# How do I answer this question on counting?

Tags: combinatorics

I know that this question is pretty simple to answer, but I am just not able to.

A class has 100 students.

40 are good in calculus.

70 are good in trigonometry.

21 are good in neither calculus nor trigonometry.

How many are good at both?

I know that I need to apply some variation of the formula
$|P ∪ Q| = |P| ∪ |Q| - |P ∩ Q|$

Where $P$ is the number of students good in calculus, and $Q$ is the number of students good in trigonometry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's try to answer this without using complex formulas. The first thing to know is how many are good at calculus and/or trigonometry. We can substract those who are not good at both from the total student (good at either= 100-21 = 79). Now the 79 people must consists of people who are only good at calculus, only good at trigonometry and good at both.Let the number of people good at both be $x$, and I believe there is enpugh information to solve this.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Based on the data and your interpretation of it, we have that those who are "good at neither calculus nor trigonometry" is $(P\cup Q)^c$. Given this, what is $P\cup Q$?